# Is coproc <command> the same as <command> &?

Tags: bash, coprocesses

I have read that `$coproc < command >` is different from `$< command > &` in that `coproc` will execute `command` in a sub-shell process.

But when I tested it, it worked just like `$< command > &`. The test is as follow:

First: test the behavior of `$< command > &`.

1. Run `$nano &` on *tty1*
2. On another tty, output from `$ps -t tty1 --forest` indicates nano process is child process of the -bash process (login bash shell process -> no sub-shell process was created)

Second: test the behavior of `$coproc < command >`

1. Run `$coproc nano` on *tty1*
2. On another tty, output from `$ps -t tty1 --forest` is the same as above (no sub-shell process was created)

So is `$coproc < command >` simply the same as `$< command > &`?

The shell used was a **bash shell**

Answer (score 4):

`coproc utility` is not the same as `utility &` in `bash`.

With `coproc utility` you get an array, `COPROC`, that contains the standard input and output filedescriptors of `utility`.  You may then do things like

```
#!/bin/bash

coproc bc -l

for (( k = 0; k < 50; ++k )); do
  printf '2.3*%d + 1\n' "$k" >&${COPROC[1]}
  read -u "${COPROC[0]}" a
  printf '%.2f\n' "$a"
done

kill "$COPROC_PID"
```

Here, `bc -l` is a co-process and acts like a "arithmetic computation service" for the shell loop, taking expressions to compute on its standard input and giving back results on its standard output.

As far as I can tell, `bash` also only supports *one* co-process at any one time.

The `ksh93` shell also supports co-processes, but the syntax is totally different (but somewhat sleeker).  This is the equivalent `ksh93` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh93

bc -l |&
coproc_pid=$!

for (( k = 0; k < 50; ++k )); do
  print -p -f '2.3*%d + 1\n' "$k"
  read -p a
  printf '%.2f\n' "$a"
done

kill "$coproc_pid"
```

Here, it's the `-p` option to `print` and `read` that makes it communicate with the co-process (the process started with `|&`) rather than using some explicit filedescriptor.

Comment: I am still investigating your answer, but just to make it clear, so the difference between `coproc` and `&' in bash isn't the creation of a sub-shell process?

Answer (score 2):

The difference is the creation of two I/O channels, as described in `man bash`:

> A coprocess is executed asynchronously in a subshell, as if the
>   command had been terminated with
>          the & control operator, with a two-way pipe established between the executing shell and the coprocess.